# How to test a React component that renders a Redux-connected component as a child without providing mock Redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I have a React component like the following:

Component1.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Component2 from './Component2.js';

const Component1 = () => (<div data-test="component1-component"><Component2 /></div>);
```

Component2.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const Component2 = (props) => {
  return(
     <div data-test="component2-component">
       <h1>{`I am Component #2. Key is ${props.key}`}</h1>
     </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ key: state.key });

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Component2);
```

As you can see, `Component1` renders `Component2` as a child component and this child component is connected to Redux store. I want to write a Jest-Enzyme test case for `Component1` that tests to see whether it renders `Component2` as its child without connecting `Component2` to Redux mock store. I am looking for something like the following:

```
describe('Component1', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<Component1 />);
  const component1Component = wrapper.find({ "data-test": "component1-component" });
  const component2Component = wrapper.find({ "data-test": "component2-component" });

  it('renders the ~Component2~ as a child component', () => {
    expect(component2Component.exists()).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Currently, I am getting an error saying that the child component is not provided with the store. How do I go about testing this?

Comment: you can wrap `Component1` with a `Provider` in your test => `<Provider store={store}>
    <Component1 />
  </Provider>`

Comment: @OlivierBoissé That is not the original question

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would just shallow render your `Component1`. This means that `Component1` will be "rendered" but the Child Components of `Component1` won't be rendered. ([Documentation of the shallow rendering api](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html).)

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('Component1', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Component1 />);
  ...
```

In your example the shallow render would contain a `div` and `Component2` as Child of that div. However `Component2` is not rendered (it is basically treated like the div, which cannot be resolved further). Therefore there is no need to supply any mock store.

Note that shallow rendering `Component1` limits the test to `Component1`, `Component2` is not tested at all the test above and you should test `Component2` seperately. (Export the unconnected version of `Component2` and supply the required props to test it.)

**Complete Example**

As an example for good tests which handle connected components I would recommend the source code of [react admin](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin).

For example the SimpleForm Component (just randomely picked):

- [Component](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/form/SimpleForm.js)
- [Test](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/form/SimpleForm.spec.js)

**Side Note:**
Don't use `key` like a normal prop as it has a special use to (re)identify the component in the virtual dome. More about the usage of keys can be found in the docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) and [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key). Connecting the key prop as you did in your example would result in React recreating the component for every change of that prop.

Comment: I want to test the `Component1` and `Component2` together with `mount`

Comment: In that case you need to provide a mocked store... However I wouldn't recommend recommend that. Imo it is much better to test each functionality with one little test.

Comment: I would reommend to split your test case into 3: 1. Component1 (shallow) render result 2. Component2 render result and 3. mapStateToProps result obj

Comment: @user117829 I 've added an example.

Comment: Then how would I test whether Component1 renders Component2?

Comment: the wrapper returned by shallow exposes different contains functions. For example you could use `expect(wrapper.containsMatchingElement(<Comonent2 />).to.equal(true))`